# Can I name the labels on all my boards at the same time?

Tags: trello, trello-labels

I have a few Trello boards. I'd like the label names to be the same on all of them. I'd also like those label names to be the default for new boards. 
Is this presently possible or do I need to submit a feature request?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way to easily transfer labels from one board to another, is to create a dummy card, assign all available labels to it and then move it to the new board. In this way only the default unnamed labels have to be removed.

Comment: Wow, you saved me a lot of work. It also works if you just copy the card with all the labels to the board where you'd like to export the labels.

Comment: Genius!!! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

While you can manually give all the labels on all your boards the same names, there isn't currently an automated way to do this.  There is also not a way to set the default label names for new boards.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose if I was keen I'd set up a script but ... hey, wait - that would be harder than just typing the names in - I'll do it!

Answer (score 3):

The way to do this is to create a template for your new board and create your new board as a copy of the template.

Comment: Copying the board does not copy the labels unfortunately or at least does not copy the text on the labels!

Comment: Copying a board with Labels DOES copy the label names and colors. I do it all the time.